# virtualbox, my cpu is dual core T4200, this cpu doesnt support VT

Tags: windows-10, virtualbox, intel-pentium, dual-core

VT-x/AMD-V hardware acceleration is not available on your system. Certain guests (e.g. OS/2 and QNX) require this feature and will fail to boot without it.

so
[virtualbox error screen capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ni6o9.png)

try to use mac os(32bit snow leopard 10.6)

i got vt error

how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you start in BIOS and check if VT-d / x can be enabled? If it can be enabled, then you can enable it. If it cannot be enabled (I think that may be what you meant), then there is nothing you can do except to purchase a new computer with VT -d /x capability